# Reword a positive question into a negative one

Tags: american-english, questions

I have a list of yes/no question. I want to associate a "yes" answer with a positive meaning (desirable) for all the questions, but I am having a problem with the last question of my list:

> Does the middleware rely on XML-based protocols?

Because answering yes to this question is considered undesirable in my context.

Can be appropriate to use the following question instead? (So a "yes" answer is desirable)

> Does the middleware not rely on XML-based protocols?

If not, how can I reformulate the question?

Comment: While this might make sense to someone fluent in computer code, it makes little sense in English.  "Rely" idiomatically requires a prepositional phrase, "on ____".  Rather than prompting a yes or no response, you may get "What??"

Comment: Ask "Is the middleware **independent** of XML-based protocols?".

Comment: @Rob_Ster You are right. It was a mistake. I am learning English and sometimes I screw up. Thanks

Comment: @DanBron That is actually a good alternative. Nevertheless it would still be useful to know how to reword a positive question (if appropriate) in this context. Thanks!

Comment: Does the middleware avoid the use of any XML-based protocols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**“Is the middleware *independent* of XML-based protocols?”**

is a clearer formulation because it uses a *single negative form* in place of *not + a positive form*. You can apply this approach generally, but only where common positive and negative forms exist, which is why the word ‘reliant’ (no useful negative equivalent) was replaced by ‘dependent’.